# Cardinality is NULL in FULLTEXT index MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on multiple columns in table `bar` of database `foo`.
The output of `mysql -u root --password=pw -e "SHOW INDEX FROM foo.bar;"` is:

```
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| bar   |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | version_id        | A         |         153 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | malfunction_desc_id |            1 | malfunction_id    | A         |         153 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | created_by          |            1 | created_by        | A         |          25 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | description         |            1 | description       | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | important_notice    |            1 | important_notice  | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | localization_text   |            1 | localization_text | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | idx_ft_title        |            1 | title             | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

But table `bar` countains 153 elements with different titles. So my question is why is `Cardinality` `NULL` here? Can you explain it?

I also tried to rebuild the index, but nothing changed:

```
mysql -u root --password=pw -e "ALTER TABLE foo.bar DROP INDEX title;"
mysql -u root --password=pw -e "ALTER TABLE foo.bar ADD FULLTEXT INDEX idx_ft_title (title);"
mysql -u root --password=pw -e "ANALYZE TABLE foo.bar;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have 4 separate `FULLTEXT` indexes, one on each of 4 columns?  Did you intend to have a single index on the combination of columns?

The cardinality of FULLTEXT is not computed and would not be used.  The assumption is that an FT index is more useful than any other index.  So, it is used first (when `AND'd` with something else); and any other `WHERE` clauses won't use `INDEXes`.